# How to pass JSON as a query parameter in a HTTP request?

Tags: rest, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy stack to implement a REST based client and server. I have a service which handles `POST` request, like below:

```java
@POST
@Path("/this")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String testPost(@QueryParam("thing") String thing) {
    ...
}
```

When I call from Postman or REST client the following URI:

```
http://ip:port/base/this?thing={"id":"abc"}
```

I always get the error as

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index (pointing to =)
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Why are you putting the data in the query string when you define the end point as expecting a POST request? Why does the end point consume plain text when you want to send it JSON?

Comment: Sorry its Application JSON I have corrected it actually it's legacy code and you are write it makes no sense to have query param but can I pass JSON to query param as above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to parse a POST request, you should use @FormParam instead of @QueryParam. Then, you can make the post request doing something like this (using curl)

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d thing="{\"id\":\"abc\"}" http://ip:port/base/this
```

Comment: FormParam works , but the content type needs to set as : application/x-www-form-urlencoded